# Writing a program that takes input from a user as an array and compares it to another array to check for correct answers using a while loop

Tags: java, methods, while-loop

this is probably a really newbie issue, but I can't quite find an answer that was answered without using a for loop. I have one array set as a constant which contains the correct answers to the test. The program takes in user input and then compares it to the constant array and counts the amount of correct answers. I should not have to import any libraries and should complete the method with a while loop.
I want to iterate through the users input through the ANSWER constant and create a count for all of the correct answers.
Here is a snippet of my class (I've excluded the method that prompts the user for answers to keep things simple).\

```
public class DriverExam{
public static final char[] ANSWER = {'B','D','A','A','C','A','B','A','C','D','B','C','D','A','D','C','C','B','D','A',};
private char[] driversAnswers;
InputReader reader;

public DriverExam(){
    reader = new InputReader();
    driversAnswers = new char[20];

}
```

```
public int getTotalCorrectAnswers(){
        int correct = 0;
        int index = 0;
        while (index < ANSWER.length){
            index++;
            if(driversAnswers.equals(ANSWER)){
                correct++;
            }
            System.out.println(index);
            System.out.println(correct);
        }
        return correct;
```

The issue is most likely to do with the if statement but I can't seem to find a way to iterate through an arrays indices and compare them to another array.

EDIT: My current method looks like this:

```
 public int getTotalCorrectAnswers(){
    int correctAnswer = 0;
    int index = 0;        
    while(index < ANSWER.length){
        if(ANSWER[index]==driversAnswers[index]){
            correctAnswer++; 
            index++;
        }            
        // System.out.println(index);
        System.out.println(correctAnswer);

    }
    return correctAnswer;
```

For a couple of attempts I was getting some actual counts happening but it appeared that it would stop the counter once it encountered a different value. But as things stand now I am stuck with a result value of 0's

Comment: You never increment `index` so `while (index < ANSWER.length){` will loop forever

Comment: @ScaryWombat I had it in there earlier and removed it while tinkering around with things. Even while I have index++; in there it increments fine but even when I enter all of the answers correctly, the correct counter never increments. I am not sure if the if(driversAnswers.equals(ANSWER)) is the right expression to be making here. The debugger goes through both of the local variables then proceeds with the while loop and gets the the IF statement and then just skips down to my println statements.

Comment: No you can not compare arrays like `if(driversAnswers.equals(ANSWER)) `   You will need to iterate over the arrays checking each element.  Be careful as the sizes of the arrays may be different.

Comment: @ScaryWombat so my issue right now is understanding how to iterate over the array and check each element.

Comment: Edit your question with what you have tried, and if it does not work, help will be on its way.

Comment: @MHG the problem in your code is you've include `index++` inside the `if`statement. Put `index++` outside the `if` and inside the `while`. It will work

Answer (score 0):

as already described in the comments, you cannot compare arrays like this. `driverAnswers.equals(ANSWER)` only compares the references, in this case it will return a false, because the references are different. If you want to check an array for equality you can use `Arrays.equals(arr1, arr2)`. In this case the `equals` method is called on every element in the array. If the objects in the arrays override this method correctly, this method will return the desired result.

However, you did mention not to use other libraries. 
The simplest solution would then be to iterate through each element and check for equality

EDIT: because you don't need the else case i made a little editing here

```
while(index < ANSWER.length){
    if(driverAnswer[index] == ANSWER[index])
        correct++
    index++
}
```

Comment: Hi @h4x9r, this seems to work but what it appears to be happening is that when I run the method, if it encounters a value that is incorrect, it stops the count even if some of the succeeding inputs are correct answers. The goal for me here is to iterate through the list and increment the count for every right answer that the user inputs. Right now it seems to just give up after an incorrect answer is input.

Comment: Then unfortunately don't understand it, this should work:
   
    while(index < ANSWER.length){
        if(driverAnswer[index] == ANSWER[index])
            correct++;
     index++
      }

Answer (score 0):

*first you to check the size of the both array must equal, if it so then you can directly use **Arrays.equals** method for all correct answer else you can loop through the right answer, look out the simple iteration below*

```
int correctAnswer = 0;
        if(ANSWER.length == driversAnswers.length){
            if(Arrays.equals(ANSWER,driversAnswers))
                System.out.println("correct answer: " + driversAnswers.length);
            else{
                for (int i=0;i<ANSWER.length;i++) {
                    if(ANSWER[i]==driversAnswers[i])
                        correctAnswer++;
                }
            System.out.println("correct answer: " + correctAnswer);
            }
        }
```

> You can use while loop there instead of **for**

```
int correctAnswer = 0,index=0;
    if(ANSWER.length == driversAnswers.length){
        if(Arrays.equals(ANSWER,driversAnswers))
            System.out.println("correct answer: " + driversAnswers.length);
        else{
            while (index<ANSWER.length) {
                if(ANSWER[index]==driversAnswers[index])
                    correctAnswer++;
                index++;
            }
        System.out.println("correct answer: " + correctAnswer);
        }
    }
```

> USE THIS FOR YOUR REFERENCE

`import java.util.Arrays; 
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] ANSWER = {'B','D','A','A','C','A','B','A','C','D','B','C','D','A','D','C','C','B','D','A',};
        char[] driversAnswers = {'x','D','A','A','C','A','B','A','C','D','B','C','D','A','D','C','C','B','D','A',}; 
        int correctAnswer = 0,index=0;
        if(ANSWER.length == driversAnswers.length){
            if(Arrays.equals(ANSWER,driversAnswers))
                System.out.println("correct answer: " + driversAnswers.length);
            else{
                while (index<ANSWER.length) {
                    if(ANSWER[index]==driversAnswers[index])
                        correctAnswer++;
                    index++;
                }
            System.out.println("correct answer: " + correctAnswer);
            }
        }

    }

}`

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply. I get an infinite loop when I use the while loop you suggested.
This even though I input all of the correct answers, it never reaches the correctAnswer++ and therefore I don't get a count of any correct answers.

Comment: i told you in the beginning, you must check the size of the both array, size of the both array equals then `Arrays.equals(ANSWER,driversAnswers)` this statement will work. And infinite loop caused by your condition. Make it sense, your index is initially 0, until unless it reaches the max array size it ll execute. so index < Answer.length is right.

Comment: initially your index is 0 and ANSWER.lenght is 20, `0<20` Until the index reaches to 20, the loop will compare the element, if it is same `(driverAnswer[index] == ANSWER[index])` correct count will be increased by 1(correct++) and index also changed to next position (index++). once the index reache 20, the condition 20<20 (driverAnswer[index] == ANSWER[index]) will be false. Because 20 is equal to 20 not less than. Then you'll the get the right answers count.